# Update recyclerView Adapter on return to previous activity with newly created item

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I'm working on an App to manage my workouts based on a room database.

Here I have a recyclerview with adapter for exercises in a workout.
My current problem is that new exercises are not shown in the recyclerview after creating them and switching back to the workout-activity.

It seems like a quite easy topic (update recyclerview after returning from other activity) but I cant' get it working.

- initial load of exercises at onCreate of workout-Activity:

  ```
  class GetExercises extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, List<Exercise>>{

        @Override
        protected List<Exercise> doInBackground(Long... params){
            if (params.length == 0 || params.length > 1) return null;
            return DatabaseClient
                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                    .getAppDatabase().exerciseDao()
                    .getReferenced(params[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<Exercise> exerciseList){
            super.onPostExecute(exerciseList);
            rv_exercises.setAdapter(new Adapter_Exercise_RV(Activity_Workout_Edit.this, exerciseList));
        }
    }
  ```
- creating a new exercise and returning the id to previous workout-activity:

  ```
  class CreateExercise extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        long id;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            Exercise ex = new Exercise();
            ex.setTitle(sTitle);
            ex.setSet(sSet);
            ex.setRep(sRep);
            ex.setAsTimer(bAsTimer);

            ex.setWorkoutId(workoutId);

            id = DatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .getAppDatabase()
                    .exerciseDao()
                    .insertwithRet(ex);
            return null;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            finish(id);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "created new exercise", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    new CreateExercise().execute();
  ```
- update adapter onActivityResult at workout-activity

  ```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        long exerciseId = (long) data.getExtras().get("exerciseId");
        rv_exercises.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
  ```

the exercise is created in the database, and after reopening the workout the new exercise is shown correctly.
I do have a feeling that "notifyDataSetChanged" is not working, but can't find why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, in the next activity you are inserting an item to db, and returning its id but in `onActivityResult`, you do not add the item to the adapter, what you need to do is to fetch the item inserted to the DB, using the `exerciseId`, and then you add that item to the adapter and then you call to notify the adapter.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
      long exerciseId = (long) data.getExtras().get("exerciseId");
      GetExerciseById(exerciseId).execute();
  }
}
```

Task to get the inserted entity

```
class GetExerciseById extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Exercise>{

     long exerciseId=0;
     GetExerciseById(long exerciseId){
       this.exerciseId=exerciseId;
     }

      @Override
      protected Exercise doInBackground(Long... params){
          if (this.exerciseId == 0) return null;
          return DatabaseClient
                  .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                  .getAppDatabase().exerciseDao()
                  .getExcerciseById(exerciseId);
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Exercise exercise){
          super.onPostExecute(exerciseList);
          if(exercise==null) return;//no item found with given id;
          if(rv_exercises.getAdapter() instanceof Adapter_Exercise_RV )
          {
             Adapter_Exercise_RV adapter = (Adapter_Exercise_RV )rv_exercises.getAdapter();
             adapter.addItem(exercise);
         }
      }
  }
```

In your `Adapter_Exercise_RV` class

```
void addItem(Exercise exercise){
  yourDatalist.add(exercise);
  notifyItemInserted(yourDatalist.size()-1);
}
```

In your DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE workoutId:=exerciseId")//relative names and ids
Exercise getExcerciseById(long exerciseId)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it works like a charm! already tried asyncTask to get the item before, but i missed the part where you wrote it back to the adapter.